# How to format the text below

Tags: java, string

I am displaying a text from database. Earlier we are displaying this from an `html` file means just we are accessing that `html` file so we are able to see that text format what we have placed in that `HTML` file. Now we stored it in the database and displaying it in UI. But the thing is we are not able to display it in the required format can any one help me to do this.

The below text we displaying in UI is

User-agent:

```
 * Disallow:/national/ Disallow: /ax/en/ Disallow: /ki/fi/ Disallow: /es/en/ 
Disallow: /cbc/ Disallow: /xsd/en/ Disallow: /lg/ Disallow: /re/ like this.
```

But we need to display it in the below format

```
    User-agent * 
    Disallow:/national/ 
    Disallow: /ax/en/ 
    Disallow: /ki/fi/ 
    Disallow: /es/en/ 
    Disallow: /cbc/ 
    Disallow: /xsd/en/ 
    Disallow: /lg/ 
    Disallow: /re/
```

Like this.

Comment: the input not match the output? from where you get `Disallow: /mi/en/ 
Disallow: */us-homepage-redirect/globalprofileoffices/*` ?

Comment: can you please provide the right input and output? is the star in the beging a part of your input?

Comment: I apologise for that updated the input and output.

Comment: again `User-agent` is a part of the input?

Comment: What is the UI? Swing? If yes, component?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what jcr and cq5 are but,
Your problem seems to be the String delimiter.
if I understand, in HTML it was ok, from DB it is not.

(there are alot of GUIs that supports html subset of tags)
I would try to replace the delimiters (probably \n) with the HTML br tag.
br is the HTML way of saying break row (new line)

```
this is a line of text <br>
this is the next line
```

Comment: I tried this not working and the <br> tags also displaying along with the text.